# Convolution product for $2^{\Omega(n)}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

How can I write the multiplicative function $2^{\Omega(n)}$ as a Dirichlet product of two multiplicative functions? That's because I have to find an estimate for $\sum_{n\leq x}2^{\Omega(n)}$.

Comment: Explain what you mean by $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: The number of prime factors of n counting the multeplicity

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Dirichlet series of your function has an obvious Euler product:$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2^{\Omega(n)}}{n^s}=\prod_{p\,prime}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{p^s}},$$ but I can't see how to write that as a product of just two factors in a meaningful way.
The RHS has a lot of poles due to the many solutions of $p^s=2$ in complex $s$, making $s=0$ an essential singularity, so I don't think there is a connection to well-investigated functions.
I assume that you mean the arithmetic function usually denoted by that symbol, http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity).

Comment: No connection with $\zeta$ function ?

Comment: I tried to do what Professor vector suggest, and then multiplicate the Euler product for the zeta function to obtein an olomorphic function...

Comment: @Jean Marie I don't think so. The RHS has a lot more poles.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise of G. Tenenbaum's book "*Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory, 3rd*" in the page 59.

We have
$$ \sum_{n\leqslant x} 2^{\Omega(n)} = \frac{C_{0}}{8 \ln 2} x (\ln x)^2 + O(x\ln x),$$
where
$$C_{0}=\prod_{p>2}\left( 1+\frac{1}{p(p-2)} \right).$$

Answer (score 0):

One of possible Dirichlet products of two multiplicative functions is
$$2^{\Omega(n)} = 2^{\Omega(n)-\omega(n)}*1(n)$$
where $1(n)$ is the constant function (defined by $1(n) = 1$) and $\omega(n)$ counts each distinct prime factor.